# preg_replace and file_get_contents not reading Arabic file names

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace, file-get-contents, arabic

First it was the preg_replace not reading Arabic characters for file name so when downloading it shows .pdf only so I added the arabic characters to the preg_replace to get the file name as is. Now the file name shows as "Ø§ÙÙÙØ§Ø¹Ø¯Ø§ÙØ¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©.pdf"

I'm not sure if anything wrong with my code

```
public function download($id){
    $toReturn = study_material::where('id',$id)->first();
    if(file_exists('uploads/material/'.$toReturn->material_file)){
        $fileName = preg_replace('/[^أ-يa-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/','',$toReturn->material_title). "." .pathinfo($toReturn->material_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
        echo file_get_contents('uploads/material/'.$toReturn->material_file);
    }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_replace does not support multibyte strings, so multi-byte letters are understood by the function as separate letters. You will need to use a multi-byte compatible function like `mb_ereg_replace`.

Comment: so you mean I replace `preg_replace` with `mb_ereg_replace` this will solve the issue? Or requires further steps?